# How to access the values of a JSON element from a POST request using the Slim framework?

Tags: php, json, apache, post, slim

I'm running an Apache2 server on a Raspberry Pi and I'm facing a problem when trying to give a response to a POST request with a JSON body, I want to extract the three elements of the JSON into three variables and then give these three variables as a response with some additional text. I've tried using GET requests on this server and they work correctly, so I suppose it isn't a configuration problem, it's a problem related to the code:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;


require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$app->post('/movimiento/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {


    // Obtenemos los parámetros del body

    // Que vienen codificados en JSON

    $bodyPost = $request->getParsedBody();  
    $vi = $bodyPost['vi'];   
    $vd = $bodyPost['vd'];   
    $servo = $bodyPost['servo'];


    $response->getBody()->write("Velocidad izquierda: $vi , Velocidad derecha: $vd , Servo: $servo");

    return $response

});

$app->run();

?>
```

So if I write a request using Postman like this:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwWxy.png)

I would be expecting a response like this:
Velocidad izquierda: 50 , Velocidad derecha: 75 , Servo: 90

However, I get an empty response:
[empty response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtkq3.png)

Comment: Look in your error logs. A 500 error should have added something. Probably that you're missing `;` after `return $response`.

Comment: Wow, I'm blind haha. That was the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

## You can use like this

```
$body=$request->getBody();
$body_data[]=json_decode($body,true);
foreach ($body_data as $r){
$value=``$r["parameter"];
 }
```